# Do I need a foreign key in the EF core code first?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new at code first in entity framework and reading up on relationships, I see everyone does it differently. It might be because of earlier versions, might be the same or might be because of performance.

Let's say I have two tables Company and User.

I would set the company-to-user relationship like this:

```
public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
```

Then if I from the user-to-company perspective needed to find the company, I would have this in the User:

```
public Company Company { get; set; }
```

And do this query:

```
return await _clientContext.Users.Where(x => x.Company.Id == companyId).ToListAsync();
```

Or I could have this:

```
public int CompanyId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
public Company Company { get; set; }
```

And have this query:

```
return await _clientContext.Users.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).ToListAsync();
```

Also some define Company with the keyword virtual like this:

```
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure if every scenario is the same and doing x.CompanyId instead of x.Company.Id would actually be the same. What is used normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally recommend the first option using Shadow Properties for FKs over the second when using navigation properties. The main reason is that with the second approach there are two sources of truth. For instance with a Team referencing a Coach, some code may use `team.CoachId` while other code uses `team.Coach.CoachId`. These two values are not guaranteed to always be in sync. (depending on when you happen to check them when one or the other is updated.)

Updating references between entities via a FK property can have varied behaviour depending on whether the referenced entity is loaded or not.

What is the expected difference between if want to update a team's coach:

```
var teamA = context.Teams.Single(x => x.TeamId == teamId);
```

If Team has a Coach navigation property and a CoachId FK reference I could do...

```
teamA.CoachId = newCoachId;
```

If TeamA's old coach ID was 1, and the newCoachId = 2, what do you think happens if I have code that lazy loads the coach before SaveChanges?

```
var coachName = teamA.Coach.Name;
```

You might expect that since the Coach hadn't been loaded yet it would load in Coach #2's name, but it loads Coach #1 because the change hasn't been committed even though teamA.CoachId == 2.  If you check the Coach reference after `SaveChanges` you get Coach #2.

Depending on whether lazy loading is enabled or not you can get a bit strange behaviour by setting a FK property where navigation properties are nulled. Even when eager loading, changing a FK property will potentially trigger a new lazy load if that new entity isn't already tracked:

```
var teamA = context.Teams.Include(x => x.Coach).Single(x => x.TeamId == teamId);
teamA.CoachId == newCoachId;
var coachName = teamA.Coach.Name; // Still points to Coach #1's name as expected.
context.SaveChanges();
coachName = teamA.Coach.Name; // Triggers lazy load and return new coach's name.
```

Saving a FK against an entity that has eager loaded the reference does not automatically re-populate referenced entities. So for instance if you have lazy loading disabled, the same above code:

```
context.SaveChanges();
coachName = teamA.Coach.Name; // Potential NullReferenceException on teamA.Coach.
```

This will potentially trigger a null reference exception *unless* the new coach happens to be tracked by the DbContext prior to SaveChanges being called. If the DbContext is tracking the entity, the new reference will be swapped in on SaveChanges, otherwise it is nulled. (With lazy loading this is covered by the new lazy load call after it was nulled)

When working with navigation properties my default recommendation is to hide FK properties as Shadow Properties. (For EF6 this means using `.Map(x => x.MapKey())`. For relationships where I only care about the ID, I will expose the FK with no navigation property. So, one or the other. (Such as lookups or bounded contexts where I want raw speed.)

I will deviate sparingly from this for exposing FKs for relationships I may inspect by ID frequently, and treat it as read-only, but still have infrequent need of the navigation property. An example of this would be `CreatedBy` / `CreatedByUserId`. Many queries may inspect the CreatedByUserId for data filtering, while some projections may want the CreatedBy.Name etc. A record's CreatedBy doesn't change so I avoid potential pitfalls of the data getting out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Your second scenario is used normally.

i.e.

```
public int CompanyId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
public Company Company { get; set; }
And have this query:

return await _clientContext.Users.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).ToListAsync();
```